# TTPhotoViewController - disable dragging

Tags: objective-c, ios, three20, ttphotoviewcontroller

I'm trying to customize the three20 `TTPhotoViewController` so that the first & last images cannot be dragged.

Example of what I am trying to prevent.
https://plus.google.com/photos/109413514618904450093/albums/5730490807945885537?authkey=CMTi6OfqhLS2NQ

The image shows the currently selected image has been dragged upwards. This behaviour does not occur on the central images only the first & last.

The code responsible for this behaviour is in the `TTScrollView`. If it was a uiscrollview I would just set bounces to NO.

Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this result?

I think the issue is in `TTScrollView:resistPageEdges` but my hacking has left me nowhere

Answer (score 0):

TTPhotoViewController delegates TTScrollViewDelegate.
TTScrollViewDelegate has -(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(TTScrollView *).
TTScrollView has (void)cancelTouches.
Therefore, you can write this in your own subclass of TTPhotoViewController.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(TTScrollView *)scrollView {
    [scrollView cancelTouches];
}
```

Every time a user try to drag, it will cancel any active touches and resets everything to an untouched state.